# How to create columns for each category of a dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a column in a dataframe, which has 6 categorical variables. I would like create 1 column for each category. Until now, I have used pivot_table but it does not seems a right ans, as I dont want to use any aggfunc and simply want to return dataframe with same corresponding values. Below in my dataframe sample:

```
        Date        Region                  Total confirmed deaths (deaths)
6452    2020-03-03  Asia                    0
10514   2020-01-02  Asia                    0
1416    2020-01-21  Europe                  0
9595    2020-02-06  Asia                    1
12221   2020-01-07  Europe                  0
12828   2020-01-14  Rest of the world       1
6232    2020-03-07  Europe                  197
10812   2020-01-05  Rest of America         0
11984   2020-04-18  Rest of the world       37
6572    2020-03-28  Rest of the world       1
1297    2020-03-19  Asia                    1
4851    2020-03-20  Rest of the world       0
```

Below is the code, which I have used for pivot table:

```
pivoted = df.pivot_table(index='Date', columns='Region', values='Total confirmed deaths (deaths)')

pivoted.resample('W')
```

Comment: why is pivot not working?

Comment: @GustavoMaia It works alright but I dont want to use any aggfunc parameter and simply want to return dataframe with same corresponding values. SO is there any other way?

Comment: @Saurabh if you don't want to use an aggfunc param then how do you want to handle the possibility of there being multiple rows with the same `'Date'` and `'Region'` values?

Comment: @Phillyclause89 Thanks for asking this question, I got my answer now. I understood the duplicacy in my data. Thus, df.pivot_table() seems alright now.

Comment: happy to hear you got it worked out. You might consider using `numpy.sum` as the argument for the `aggfunc` param. By default it will use `numpy.mean` which may or may not be what you want to apply to your data from the deaths column.